# Javacard - protect RSA private key with something other than a plaintext pin?

Tags: java, cryptography, smartcard, javacard

Say I wanted to protect use of a RSA Private Key on a Javacard with something stronger than a plaintext PIN... such as a custom challenge/response mechanism. How would I accomplish this?

I see that `javacard.framework.OwnerPIN::setValidatedFlag()` is supposed to unlock the card without supplying a PIN. But if I try to call that from my main application I get this error when compiling:

`error: setValidatedFlag(boolean) has protected access in OwnerPIN`

Comment: Have you created instance of OwnerPin ?

Comment: Yes, that's how the plaintext pin is defined.

Answer (score 1):

> Say I wanted to protect use of a RSA Private Key on a Javacard with something stronger than a plaintext PIN... such as a custom challenge/response mechanism. How would I accomplish this?

You'd *program it*, making sure that the challenge is random, the verification of the response time constant and the resulting authentication state protected against change.

There are many challenge / response protocols possible, there isn't a ready made implementation. That said, all the ingredients (random number generator, ciphers, MAC algorithms, transient storage - i.e. RAM - and a Turing complete bytecode interpreter) are there.

If you're going with a challenge / response protocol then you would not use the `OwnerPIN` class but use a transient state.

---

Here is a quick mockup on how you can perform this kind of authentication, but note that it wasn't even compiled against Java Card.

The protection against attacks are kind of randomly thrown in; not every platform would need them and there are certainly other kinds of protection possible (such as comparing against inverted values, random delays, RAM state honeypots etc. etc. etc.).

```
private static final short TRUE = 0x3A5C;
private static final short FALSE = (short) 0xA3C5;

private static final short SINGLETON_SIZE = 1;
private static final short SINGLETON_INDEX = 0;

private static final short NOT_AUTHENTICATED = 0x0000;
private static final short AUTHENTICATED = 0x5C3A;

private final short[] authenticationState;

TransientState() {
    authenticationState = JCSystem.makeTransientShortArray(SINGLETON_SIZE, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
}

private void authenticate() {
    // reset authentication state
    authenticationState[SINGLETON_INDEX] = NOT_AUTHENTICATED;

    // perform the challenge / response authentication (mock)
    short authenticationSucceeded = TRUE;

    if (authenticationSucceeded == TRUE) {

        // check against perturbation of flow control

        authenticationState[SINGLETON_INDEX] = AUTHENTICATED;

        // check against perturbation of flow control

    }
}

private void sign() {
    if (authenticationState[SINGLETON_INDEX] != AUTHENTICATED) {
        // throw exception, e.g. SECURITY_CONDITIONS_NOT_SATISFIED
    }

    if (authenticationState[SINGLETON_INDEX] == AUTHENTICATED) {

        // check against perturbation of flow control

        // create signature

        // check against perturbation of flow control

        // verify signature (could protect the private key against exposure)

        // check against perturbation of flow control

        // return signature
    }
}

public void process() {
    switch (ins) {
    case INS_MUTUAL_AUTHENTICATE:
        authenticate();
        break;
    case INS_PSO_SIGN:
        sign();
        break;
    default:
        // throw INS_NOT_SUPPORTED or something
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I would have to code something myself. My question is how do I protect the private key stored on the card the same way `OwnerPIN` does when writing my own verification method - so that the card will not sign/encrypt anything before verification occurs.

Comment: The OwnerPIN class keeps secure state. You could for instance store state within a 16 bit short where the possible states have a large Hamming distance. You don't *require* OwnerPIN to keep secure state, although it certainly helps to have the platform do this for you.

Comment: Would you be able to share an example of this? I totally understand that I would need to keep track of state myself, but still I do not understand how to tell the system "The cardholder has been validated and is now allowed to access the private key object for encrypt/sign operations"

Comment: @Justin You are overthinking this a little... Just create a `short` transient variable as Maarten said. `0xFFFF` will mean "authenticated", `0x0000` "not authenticated". You will set the variable to `0xFFFF` after successful authentication and check it before accessing the private key. It is really that simple. It is all in your applet, you don't have to "tell the system" anything.

Comment: @vojta Right. Except that `0x0000` and particularly `0xFFFF` are default states of the EEPROM / Flash after reset, so another value with as many bits set as unset should be preferred. Otherwise sharks with lasers may attack your product (did I just compare testing labs with sharks? Uh oh.).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes OP wants to store the state in RAM, if I am not mistaken...

Comment: @vojta That's true, and 0x0000 is a good option for "not authenticated" as it is the value of the RAM after reset. I'd still choose a different value for authenticated, but that's not a large issue.

Answer (score -1):

> Say I wanted to protect use of a RSA Private Key on a Javacard with
>   something stronger than a plaintext PIN... such as a custom
>   challenge/response mechanism. How would I accomplish this?

I suppose you are generating public/private key pair in an offcard entity.
Use secure channel protocol and personalize the key on the card using store-data or some of your custom command.

> error: setValidatedFlag(boolean) has protected access in OwnerPIN

I did not find any connection of this API with securely storing private key, but this method is only available for a child class of `javacard.framework.OwnerPIN`, it is a protected method. So you wont be able to call it.